# Client validation with partial view not working in IE

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am adding partial view and after successful completion, I had called validation plugin. But client validation is not working in IE but works in Chrome and Firefox. Any suggestions please.

```
$('form').removeData("validator");
$.validator.unobtrusive.parse(document);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try rendering the partial view inside a DIV, and use the below line to add client validation of the view.

```
      $.validator.unobtrusive.parse($("#YOURDIVID"));
```

No need to call the 1st line u mentioned above

```
   $('form').removeData("validator"); // NOT REQUIRED
```

Comment: Yes, it had something to do with this. But had to keep removeData as well.